# C++ class and interlinked objects forming a cycle

Tags: c++

How could i achieve interlocked object structure that makes a cycle in C++

```
class Foo
{
    Bar bar;
};

class Bar
{
    Foo foo;
};
```

Comment: Via forward declaration and pointers/references.

Comment: how dowe define the rest of the class in that case, both the classes contains many complex functions

Comment: what would `sizeof(Foo)` be?

Comment: Cant predict size of Foo at this time. How would size matter?

Comment: @user2368055, use forward declaration with pointer/reference, then define the classes in the cpp file

Answer (score 6):

### Foo.h

```
#include <memory>

class Bar; // Forward declare Bar class

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar; // Use pointer so that header include is not necessary
};
```

### Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h" // Now include bar (in the cpp file to avoid circular includes)

Foo::Foo() :
    bar(new Bar())
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

Use the same setup with `Bar.h` and `Bar.cpp`.

### Edit 1

**Note:** The above code assumes a compiler supporting C++11 is used. However, if this is not the case then a raw pointer (e.g., `Bar* bar`) should be used and the `destructor` must be implented to call `delete bar`. This is necessary to avoid leaking the resource; of course the above assumes `Foo` and `Bar` owning their member pointer is the correct behavior for these classes but it can easily be changed this is not the correct assumption.

Comment: and how would the class definition be in this case?

Comment: In the `Foo.cpp` file you're free to use the class instance of the `Bar` class (i.e., `bar`) as you normally would.

Comment: I added a constructor so that I could provide an example of some kind of implementation for the `Foo` class.

Comment: Depending on OP's use case, `weak_ptr`s may be the better option.

Comment: @AndyG Yes, I'm a making an assumption that the class owns the pointer. Which I thought was reasonable because in his question the objects were stack allocated members of the class (i.e., only that class could own the object).

Comment: You should probably point out any language restrictions (c++11?), since this will likely become the accepted answer. I think your assumption that the class owns the pointer is sound, and would keep the unique_ptr

Comment: @mjs Per your suggesstion, I editted the answer to include C++11 support is required.

Answer (score 0):

The usual means is by using forward declarations. To do this you should split these into seperate header files, eg

```
//foo.h
class Bar;

class Foo
{
     Bar* myBar; //Note this must be a pointer
     int someVal;
     int someFunc();

}


//bar.h
class Foo;
class Bar
{
     Foo* myFoo; //Again, must be a pointer
}
```

The header files should not include each other. There are some restrictions, in that you can only use pointer-to-foo and pointer-to-bar until the compiler has encountered the actual declaration. This is because the compiler knows how much memory to allocate for a pointer, however would not know how big the required object would be.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28697923/2139094) which achieves the same thing, using smart pointers. My solution is a simpler, pure C++ version, however James Adikin's is probably preferable where supported.