# Circular inclusion issue with extended class c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Can you figure out how to solve this circular inclusion problem?

C extends B and B includes A. A includes C. Every forward declaration I tried hasn't worked.

**Errors**

Error   1   error C2504: 'B' : base class undefined 
Error   2   error C3668: 'C::c' : method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods

**File A.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include "C.h"

struct A
{
    A();

    C c;
};
```

**File B.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include "A.h"

struct A;

struct B
{
    virtual void c() = 0;

    A* a;
};
```

**File C.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include "B.h"

struct B;

struct C : public B
{
    void c() override;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is always the same and it looks like you were on the right track. However, you're not using forward declartions correctly. There should be many examples of how to do this for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697567/c-class-and-interlinked-objects-forming-a-cycle/28697923#28697923).

### B.h

```
// Why are including "A.h" here, this is causing your circular include
// issue, it needs to be moved to your implementation (e.g., "B.cpp")
#include "A.h"

struct A; // Forward declaration, good

struct B
{
    virtual void c() = 0;

    A* a; // A pointer only requires the above forward declartion
};
```

### C.h

```
#include "B.h" // Necessary since you're extending `B`

struct B; // This forward declaration is superfluous and should be removed

struct C : public B
{
    void c() override;
};
```