# Cannot use enum from another file: " does not name a type" error

Tags: c++, class, enumeration

I have `A.h` where I am defining an `enum` like this. `A.h` is a class but my `enum` is outside the class.

```
enum testEnum {
 item1,
 item2
};
class A
{
...
};
```

I want to use the same `enum` from some other `class B`.

```
#include "A.h"
class B{
public:
  void useEnumHere(testEnum item);
};
```

I am getting error at the line of `useEnumHere` method declartion;

```
error: 'testEnum' does not name a type
```

Comment: you forget the `;` for enum. otherwise I think it's OK.

Comment: and `#include A.h` should be `#include "A.h"`

Comment: I just incorrectly copied it..`"A.h"` and `;` are already there

Comment: Does your A.h include B.h? If so, this is a [circular inclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697567/c-class-and-interlinked-objects-forming-a-cycle/28697923#28697923) problem.

Comment: In that case, there must be an issue in some code you haven't shown us, such as a namespace declaration that you're forgetting about. Because that's the correct way to refer to an enum.

Comment: I think we are going to need a [mcve] to take a crack at this without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

A forward declaration is enough in the header file if you don't use it. Include it in the cpp file.

```
enum testEnum;
class B{...};
```

Comment: True, but if A.h is being included correctly, this is completely unnecessary. The question is,  or should be, "Why isn't B picking up the definitions from A?" and the Asker has not provided enough information to be able to answer this.

Comment: @user4581301 That's completely true. But a hint to reduce dependencies doesn't hurt.